# Implementing JqMath Android to display Formulas

Tags: javascript, android, web, webview, jqmath

I have read about JqMath and how to implement it here at Stackoverflow, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

**What I want**
Display math equations, constants and formulas

**What I've done**
1. Added these files to my assets folder:
jqmath-0.4.3.css
jqmath-0.4.3.js
jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js
jquery-1.4.3.js
jquery-1.4.3.min.js
jscurry-0.4.0.js
jscurry-0.4.0.min.js

2. Written this code:

   ```
   private WebView webView;
   private WebSettings webSettings;

   //In the constructor
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webSettings = webView.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   path = "file:///android_asset/";

   // In the method where I want to set the content
   js = "<html><head>"
           + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+path+"jqmath-0.4.3.css'>"
           + "<script src='"+path+"jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
           + "<script src='"+path+"jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js'></script>"
           + "</head><body>"
           + "$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</body></html>";
   webView.loadData(js,  "text/html",  "UTF-8");
   ```

**The problem**
According to the logcat:

```
    E/WifiStateMachine: CMD_START_SCAN : connected mode and no configuration
    4306-4306/com.fredrikandcasper.matteguide I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)]                 
    "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/jqmath-
    0.4.3.css", source: data:text/html,<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' 
    href='file:///android_asset/jqmath-0.4.3.css'><script 
    src='file:///android_asset/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script><script 
    src='file:///android_asset/jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js'></script></head>
    <body>$$x={-b%C2%B1%E2%88%9A{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</body></html> (1)
```

And the same error for the other files: jquery-1.4.3.min.js & jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!